# App has been not registered in react native

Tags: reactjs, command-line-interface, native

Invariant Violation: "FirstProject" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

What will be the solution of this when i run the react native app getting the error app not registered